# How do I iterate over a DataTable and get groups of rows based on a column value?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that essentially looks like this:

```
Id   |    parentId
__________________
1    |    100
2    |    100
3    |    200
4    |    300
5    |    300
6    |    300
7    |    400
8    |    400
```

As you can see each row has a unique ID and is assigned to a parent by the parent's ID (Int64). Additionally each parent may contain multiple rows.
In my case the parent is a ticket in our system and the row is an attachment to that ticket.

I want to iterate over the `DataTable` so that I can process the attachments but I need to do it in groups based on the `parentId` values. This is because if just one of the attachments fails to process then that whole group fails and must be rolled back, I will then continue to process other tickets.

I can achieve this with an if statement similar to this (pseudo-code):

```
var currentParent = 0;
foreach (var row in table.Rows)
{
    if (row["parentId"] == currentParent)
    {
        // Same group
    }
    else
    {
        // New group
    }
    currentParent = row["parentId"];
}
```

This works but I feel it is messy because if the first item in a group of 100 fails it will still have to go over the remaining 99 items.

I've been trying to look at a solution that uses `LINQ` and `IEnumerable` to grab each group of rows and possibly put them into their own temporary `DataTable`. This would make it easy to iterate over and skip if an error is encountered. Unfortunately I'm not sure what functions I'm even looking for so I'm stuck.

I thought `GroupBy` sounded right and tried this:

```
var results = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<Int64>("parentId"));
```

Unfortunately this returns just 4 rows which makes sense as in my example there are only 4 different parents.

I was looking for something more like this:

```
var count = temporaryDataTable.Rows.Count();

// After first "grab" of a group 'count' is 2 for parentId 100  
// temporaryDataTable contains Id values 1 & 2.

// After second "grab" 'count' is 1 for parentId 200  
// temporaryDataTable contains Id value 3.

// After third "grab" 'count' is 3 for parentId 300  
// temporaryDataTable contains Id values 4, 5 & 6.

// Last "grab" 'count' is 2 for parentId 400  
// temporaryDataTable contains Id values 7 & 8.
```

Alternatively I may be way off the mark here so if there's something better suited than `LINQ` to get the data in this manner then please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Having identified the (4) groups, can you not then `foreach` apply a filter on the table?

Comment: Good point! I'll do some testing and see which method I think is most appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: Pop your select statement into Claudiu's foreach loop - et voila!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you grouped the `results`, you can use this loop to iterate over your groups:

```
foreach (var group in results)
{
    // This will get the parentId value in the group.
    var parentId = group.Key;

    // This will get all the Ids contained in the group.
    foreach (var Id in group)
    {
        // Do something with Id. If something goees wrong
        // and you want to proceed with the next group,
        // just put a break; inside this foreach.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, can't believe I was so close! I had the iteration for results and the key, didn't realise it was as easy as iterating over groups as well. Thank you!